# Homology of infinite matroids of finite rank

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra, simplicial-complexes, matroid-theory, linear-independence

Bjorner has a great [paper](https://www.cefns.nau.edu/%7Efalk/classes/690/extras/bjorner.pdf) about the homology of independence complexes of finite matroids, which is the usual context in matroid theory as far as I understand. However, I've also been told that often times infinite matroids of finite rank often behave much like their finite counterparts, and so I have hope many of the results generalize - indeed, from the few arguments I've looked over, many of the concepts seem to generalize in natural ways. I could follow the paper and try to recreate the results "from scratch" in this way for infinite matroids, but I wanted to know if analogues of Bjorner's paper in the infinite case already exist in the literature.

I'm especially interested in infinite matroids realizable over infinite fields, e.g. the matroid of lines in a finite-dimensional Q-vector space, if there is literature specifically about that.

I don't know much about matroid theory, so I apologize if I'm missing obvious terminology or idea!